# clang++ adress sanitizer shows memory leaks even when there is no leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, clang++, address-sanitizer

I build with brew version of clang++ and use adress sanitizer to look for memory leaks and it gives memory leak on every program even programs without any leak.

```
 clang++  -fsanitize=thread main.cpp -g
```

```
int main() {

    auto *p = new int;
    delete p; // no leak
    return 0;
}
```

I have been using the following commands. I expect there shouldn’t be any leaks however it shows the leaks from system  libraries couldn't make any sense.

> ```
> clang++  -fsanitize=address main.cpp -g
> export ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1
> export MallocNanoZone=0
> ./a.out
> ```

```
=================================================================
==74341==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 1952 byte(s) in 61 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x1066d25e5 in wrap_calloc+0xa5 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x475e5) (BuildId: e487ca41363b3ac1b8e9e49fecb969fb2400000010000000000a0a0000000d00)
    #1 0x7ff81bb972ee in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x85 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x52ee) (BuildId: aca7ef61285336998c1f1c0ab93ad6be32000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #2 0x7ff81bb95646 in map_images_nolock+0x160e (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x3646) (BuildId: aca7ef61285336998c1f1c0ab93ad6be32000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #3 0x7ff81bb93fda in map_images+0x42 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x1fda) (BuildId: aca7ef61285336998c1f1c0ab93ad6be32000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #4 0x7ff81bbe04c2 in invocation function for block in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(mach_header const*, void*, mach_header const*, void const*), void (*)(unsigned int, _dyld_objc_notify_mapped_info const*))+0x27c (dyld:x86_64+0xfffffffffff7e4c2) (BuildId: 28fd207157f3387387bfe4f674a82de632000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #5 0x7ff81bbdaffe in dyld4::RuntimeState::withLoadersReadLock(void () block_pointer)+0x2e 
Direct leak of 1952 byte(s) in 61 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x1066d25e5 in wrap_calloc+0xa5 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x475e5) (BuildId: e487ca41363b3ac1b8e9e49fecb969fb2400000010000000000a0a0000000d00)
    #1 0x7ff81bb972ee in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x85 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x52ee) (BuildId: aca7ef61285336998c1f1c0ab93ad6be32000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #2 0x7ff81bb973ac in realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*)+0x143 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x53ac) (BuildId: aca7ef61285336998c1f1c0ab93ad6be32000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #3 0x7ff81bb95646 in map_images_nolock+0x160e (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x3646) (BuildId: aca7ef61285336998c1f1c0ab93ad6be32000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #4 0x7ff81bb93fda in map_images+0x42 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x1fda) (BuildId: aca7ef61285336998c1f1c0ab93ad6be32000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #5 0x7ff81bbe04c2 in invocation function for block in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(mach_header const*, void*, mach_header const*, void const*), void (*)(unsigned int, _dyld_objc_notify_mapped_info const*))+0x27c (dyld:x86_64+0xfffffffffff7e4c2) (BuildId: 28fd207157f3387387bfe4f674a82de632000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #6 0x7ff81bbdaffe in dyld4::RuntimeState::withLoadersReadLock(void () block_pointer)+0x2e (dyld:x86_64+0xfffffffffff78ffe) (BuildId: 28fd207157f3387387bfe4f674a82de632000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #7 0x7ff81bbe023f in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(mach_header const*, void*, mach_header const*, void const*), void (*)(unsigned int, _dyld_objc_notify_mapped_info const*))+0x5f (dyld:x86_64+0xfffffffffff7e23f) (BuildId: 28fd207157f3387387bfe4f674a82de632000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #8 0x7ff81bc045e3 in dyld4::APIs::_dyld_objc_register_callbacks(_dyld_objc_callbacks const*)+0x89 (dyld:x86_64+0xfffffffffffa25e3) (BuildId: 28fd207157f3387387bfe4f674a82de632000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #9 0x7ff81bb93e3e in _objc_init+0x4f6 (libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x1e3e) (BuildId: aca7ef61285336998c1f1c0ab93ad6be32000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #10 0x7ff81bd850bf in _os_object_init+0xc (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x20bf) (BuildId: 817339a1d03e3e549c47acacf69f619332000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #11 0x7ff81bd92d34 in libdispatch_init+0x16a (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0xfd34) (BuildId: 817339a1d03e3e549c47acacf69f619332000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #12 0x7ff827b2d894 in libSystem_initializer+0xed (libSystem.B.dylib:x86_64+0x1894) (BuildId: 862b6758852e3e89a4fed564a7163e2532000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #13 0x7ff81bbea617 in invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const+0xab (dyld:x86_64+0xfffffffffff88617) (BuildId: 28fd207157f3387387bfe4f674a82de632000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #14 0x7ff81bc29de8 in invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const+0xf1 (dyld:x86_64+0xfffffffffffc7de8) (BuildId: 28fd207157f3387387bfe4f674a82de632000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #15 0x7ff81bc1def6 in invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const+0x22c (dyld:x86_64+0xfffffffffffbbef6) (BuildId: 28fd207157f3387387bfe4f674a82de632000000200000000100000000000d00)

...

    #23 0x7ff81bbd5368 in dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)+0xe9e (dyld:x86_64+0xfffffffffff73368) (BuildId: 28fd207157f3387387bfe4f674a82de632000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #24 0x7ff81bbd4280 in start+0x8f0 (dyld:x86_64+0xfffffffffff72280) (BuildId: 28fd207157f3387387bfe4f674a82de632000000200000000100000000000d00)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 4288 byte(s) leaked in 134 allocation(s).
```

and my clang++ version:

```
Homebrew clang version 15.0.6
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
```

on macOS 13.0.1

Comment: The leak detector tells you where the leaked allocation was allocated. If the leak doesn't originate anywhere in your code, what are you going to do about it? There are bugs in the runtime implementations and sometimes leak detectors get false positives from stuff that will be released AFTER the leak detector unhooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same situation here as the OP.  I don't know what the root cause is (false positive vs. true memory leak in `realizeClassWithoutSwift()`), but you can configure LeakSanitizer to suppress detected leaks in the memory leak report:

Create a file `lsan.supp` with

```
leak:realizeClassWithoutSwift
```

and then use it when running your binary:

```
ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 LSAN_OPTIONS=suppressions=lsan.supp my_binary
```

More details at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#suppressing-memory-leaks.

Answer courtesy to GitHub user's [willmcpherson2](https://github.com/willmcpherson2) comment at [google/sanitizers/issues/1501](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1501#issuecomment-1102262664).